# Cannot access methods inside custom View class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I cannot seem to access any of the methods that I have implemented in my custom view class WorkoutView.

I am trying to add several of these views programmatically to a LinearLayout within the parent layout which is set using setContentView;

**Why can I not access any of the methods that are defined in the WorkoutView Class?** I need to access these methods so that I can gain the values of these each individual view (because there can be an infinite number of these views added)

Here is how I am inflating the layout I would like to use with the WorkoutView

```
    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    workoutView = (WorkoutView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_workout_layout, workoutLayout, false);
```

Here is the LinearLayout that is within the parent view that was inflated initially

```
   workoutLayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.workoutLayout);
```

Simply adding the view to the workoutLayout

```
workoutLayout.addView(workoutView);
```

Here is the XML for the Parent Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <!--    <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView" android:layout_gravity="center">-->

    <com.modup.view.CustomScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollViewLinearLayout">


<!--            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >-->

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_background_shadow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                    <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewTitle"
                                android:layout_width="35dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:src="@drawable/title"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                />


                        <com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
                                xmlns:float="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                float:fletPaddingLeft="4dp"
                                float:fletPaddingBottom="2dp">

                            <EditText
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:maxLength="75"
                                    android:maxLines="3"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:hint="Title"
                                    android:id="@+id/editText"/>


                        </com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:background="@color/material_grey_500" android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/divider" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
                            <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/skull"
                                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/imageViewDifficulty" android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
                            <Spinner
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/spinnerDifficulty" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                            <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTime" android:src="@drawable/stopwatch"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                            <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:id="@+id/spinnerTime" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
<!--            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    >

                <Button
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/add_content_selector"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonAddWorkout"/>

                <com.modup.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:id="@+id/addWorkout"
                        style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text="Add Workout"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_blue"
                        app:typeface="robotoBold" android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/workoutLayout">
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.modup.view.CustomScrollView>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/accept_content_selector"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAccept" android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_content_selector"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel" android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the XML for the WorkoutView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.modup.view.WorkoutView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/workoutView">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Workout Name"
                        android:id="@+id/etWorkoutName" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cancel_content_selector"
                        android:id="@+id/btnRemoveWorkout" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.modup.font.RobotoTextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewMuscleGroup"
                            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_blue"
                            android:text="Muscle Group"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            app:typeface="robotoBold"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dp"/>
                    <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerWorkoutGroup" android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.modup.font.RobotoTextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewSet"
                            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_blue"
                            android:text="Sets"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            app:typeface="robotoBold"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dp"/>
                    <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerSets" android:textAlignment="center" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <com.modup.font.RobotoTextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewRep"
                            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/primary_blue"
                            android:text="Reps"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            app:typeface="robotoBold"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dp"/>
                    <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerReps" android:textAlignment="center" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</com.modup.view.WorkoutView>
```

Here is the WorkoutView class

```
public class WorkoutView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
    int res_id;
    public Spinner spinnerDifficulty, spinnerTime, spinnerMuscleGroup, spinnerSets, spinnerReps;
    public EditText etWorkoutName;
    public Button btnRemoveWorkout;

    String workoutName, muscleGroup, sets, reps;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public WorkoutView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WorkoutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    init();
    }

    public WorkoutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void init() {
        spinnerDifficulty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDifficulty);
        spinnerReps = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerReps);
        spinnerSets = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSets);
        spinnerMuscleGroup = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerWorkoutGroup);
        spinnerTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTime);
        etWorkoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWorkoutName);
        btnRemoveWorkout = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveWorkout);
        btnRemoveWorkout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public String getReps() {
        reps = spinnerReps.getSelectedItem().toString();
        return reps;
    }

    public String getWorkoutName() {
        workoutName = etWorkoutName.getText().toString().trim();
        return workoutName;
    }

    public String getMuscleGroup() {
        muscleGroup = spinnerMuscleGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
        return muscleGroup;
    }

    public String getSets() {
        sets = spinnerSets.getSelectedItem().toString();
        return sets;
    }

    public SingleWorkout getAll() {
        //to be designed
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnRemoveWorkout:
                Log.e("DID THIS WORK?", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I cannot make a call to the methods within the WorkoutView such as

```
workoutView.getReps();
```

it results in a NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.modup.view.WorkoutView.getReps(WorkoutView.java:51)
        at com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment.onClick(CreateFragment.java:197)
```

**UPDATE**

I added the init(); method to the constructor and it results in this error

```
03-06 22:48:06.952  22106-22106/com.modup.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.modup.app, PID: 22106
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.modup.view.WorkoutView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment.onClick(CreateFragment.java:195)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment.onClick(CreateFragment.java:195)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.modup.view.WorkoutView.init(WorkoutView.java:57)
        at com.modup.view.WorkoutView.<init>(WorkoutView.java:39)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.modup.fragment.CreateFragment.onClick(CreateFragment.java:195)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How is workoutView declared?

Comment: Declare `workoutView` as` WorkoutView workoutView` and _not_ `View workoutView`. Same as what @JoeMaher is saying.

Comment: WorkoutView workoutView; and then it is inflated inside an init() method. The inflation is listed inside the question.

Comment: @ItzHoudini And where is it that you can't use methods defined in `WorkoutView`.

Comment: Just for clarification, something like:


`inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();`

`WorkoutView workoutView = (WorkoutView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_workout_layout, workoutLayout, false);`

`workoutView.getReps();`

Throws a compilation error?

Comment: Because something like `getView().getReps()` will throw a compilation error as far as i know

Comment: It does throw a NullPointerException. I will add it to the question.

Comment: The way I see it: you're telling us a few different things: unable to use methods, ClassCastException.... Tell us what you want to do, and we can focus on that.

Comment: I just want to be able to add many instances of this WorkoutView, and at a later time retrieve the values from each instance individually through the methods provided in the WorkoutView class. I added the ClassCastException because I was not sure it if was relevant to the issue I was experiencing.

Comment: @ItzHoudini You never call `init()` inside `WorkoutView`. So, `spinnerReps` is never initialized, hence the NPE. Also, NPE is an unchecked exception. Saying you are not able to access methods of a class because of a NPE is incorrect.

Comment: I see. I updated the question. I am attempting to call init() inside the constructor which is being called when I add the view. This is resulting in an error which I have posted.

Comment: @ItzHoudini You need to wait until the layout has been inflated. Calling `init()` inside the constructor will trow an NPE because `btnRemoveWorkout` is _still_ null. The NPE is thrown at: `btnRemoveWorkout.setOnClickListener(this);` . You should override `onFinishInflate()` inside `WorkoutView` and call `init()`  after the `super.onFinishInflate()` call.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you, I did not know about onFinishInflate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot make a call to the methods within the WorkoutView…it results in a NullPointerException

This is because the child views you are expecting to be set by `findViewById()` are not yet valid. In this first case, its was the attempt to access `getSelectedItem()`

> I added the init(); method to the constructor and it results in this error

Same reason, in this case it's the call to `setOnClickListener()` at the end of `init()`.

In both cases, you are assuming that the view hierarchy defined in your XML file has been full inflated by the time the constructor is called…this is false. When the constructor is called, all the child views underneath haven't been inflated and added yet.

If you want to get references to your child views in the way that your `init()` method is written, you have to wait until the `onFinishInflate()` method is triggered ([docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate())). Override this method and call `init()` there…not in the constructors:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate () {
    init();
}
```

Then your attempts to call your accessor methods should work as expected.